# Java SQL syntax error whilst creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, create-table

I'm getting a syntax error on a create table string. I've had a look online to see if there's anything I'm missing but I can't spot what's wrong.

```
//SQL Statement to create table on phpmyadmin if not exists
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(\n"
            + "id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT \n"
            + "username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL \n"
            + "realname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL \n"
            + "password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL \n"
            + "email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL \n"
            + "gym VARCHAR(100) \n"
            + "belt VARCHAR(100) \n"
            + "dateofbirth DATE NOT NULL \n"
            + "profilepic LONGBLOB \n"
            + "biography VARCHAR(1000) \n"
            + "motto VARCHAR(200) \n"
            + "PRIMARY KEY (id)\n"
            + ")";
```

Output says;

> "near 'AUTO INCREMENT
>   username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
>   realname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
>   p' at line 2"

Comment: Shouldn't there be commas between your column declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop all `\n` and replace with `,` after each column except for the last.
Also for MySql it's `AUTO_INCREMENT`, not `AUTO INCREMENT`.